# How can i compare two words which contain unicode characters?

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to create a language model which processes words and I am having problems as my corpus is in a foreign language and therefore has unicode characters such as ġ,ħ and ż but the .equals is not working on words with these letters even though I'm reading text from a text file and copying such words exactly. What can I do to fix this?

```
public class test3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    System.out.print("Enter string: ");
    line = s.nextLine();
    if(line.equals("aħħar")){
        System.out.println("Correct"); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
    }
  }
}

I have entered the word 'aħħar' and keep getting "Incorrect".
```

Comment: Please add the actual code where u need help.. update you question asap :)

Comment: Equals works just fine on strings containing Unicode characters. You have a problem with how you are reading them. E.g. Are you using the correct CharSet? Are there non-printable characters that you haven't noticed (because they're non-printable)?

Comment: @searlea Given what OP wrote you cannot say that the reference you've given is a duplicate. See what Andy wrote.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code that is not working?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @laune Sure, you're right.  I hadn't considered this could be a charset encoding issue - I saw accents and thought this the most likely answer (I guess that's why stackoverflow defaults to inserting 'Possible' in a flag-for-duplicate comment)

Comment: public class test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
  System.out.print("Enter string: ");
  line = s.nextLine();
  if(line.equals("aħħar")){
   System.out.println("Correct");
   }
   else{
    System.out.println("Incorrect");
    }
    
  }
 }
 I have entered the word 'aħħar' and keep getting incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the default encoding for reading 
from standard input (via Scanner) does not match what your operating system uses.

Note that the constructors for `Scanner` have an additional parameter `String charsetName` for the encoding type used to convert bytes from the file into characters to be scanned. Add the appropriate value which may vary between operating systems and installations.